# Listbox selection in VBA not taking place properly

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a vba code to populate the listbox selection in a textbox and the selection of listbox entry should get populated in an excel
Listbox is a 2 column listbox having name and email id. when users mouse clicks and entry in a listbox the second column having email id should be copied in an excel sheet and the first column with the name should appear in the text box
Problem i am facing is that when i click on the listbox, textbox gets populated correctly with first column value but the excel does not get populated with corresponding email id. The reason being mouse click on the row in the listbox is not making the row turn blue i.e.it is not getting highlighted as a result listbox.listindex>-1 does not get satisfied. 
Can anybody please help when the mouse click on listbox does not highlight the selected row?

```
Sub EmailId()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim str As String

'UserForm2.vCB_ActionOwner.ColumnCount = 2
'UserForm2.vCB_ActionOwner.ColumnWidths = "1 in, 1.5 in"

UserForm2.vLB_Edit_ActionOwner.ColumnCount = 2
UserForm2.vLB_Edit_ActionOwner.ColumnWidths = "1 in, 1.5 in"

UserForm2.vCB_RevisedActionOwner.ColumnCount = 2
UserForm2.vCB_RevisedActionOwner.ColumnWidths = "1 in, 1.5 in"

str = UserForm2.vTB_Edit_ActionOwner.Text
UserForm2.vLB_Edit_ActionOwner.Clear

With UserForm2
For i = 1 To TotalRows_EmailId
If InStr(1, varArray_EmailId(i, 1), str, vbTextCompare) Then
.vLB_Edit_ActionOwner.AddItem
.vLB_Edit_ActionOwner.List(.vLB_Edit_ActionOwner.ListCount - 1, 0) = varArray_EmailId(i, 1)
.vLB_Edit_ActionOwner.List(.vLB_Edit_ActionOwner.ListCount - 1, 1) = varArray_EmailId(i, 4)

End If
Next i

Private Sub vTB_Edit_ActionOwner_Change()
UserForm2.vLB_Edit_ActionOwner.Visible = True
Call EmailId
Me.vLB_ScheduleDate.Visible = True
Me.vTB_ScheduleDate.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub vLB_Edit_ActionOwner_Click()
UserForm2.vLB_Edit_ActionOwner.Visible = False
UserForm2.vTB_Edit_ActionOwner.Text = UserForm2.vLB_Edit_ActionOwner.ListIndex
End Sub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code you used. Tell which errors you get and where (or tell what your code does vs. what you expect it to do). Reading [mcve] might help to give a good example in your question.

Comment: Possible to see the code for your `Listbox_Change` or `Listbox_Click` event?

Comment: Private Sub vTB_Edit_ActionOwner_Change()
UserForm2.vLB_Edit_ActionOwner.Visible = True
Call EmailId
Me.vLB_ScheduleDate.Visible = True
Me.vTB_ScheduleDate.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub vLB_Edit_ActionOwner_Click()
UserForm2.vLB_Edit_ActionOwner.Visible = False
UserForm2.vTB_Edit_ActionOwner.Text = UserForm2.vLB_Edit_ActionOwner.ListIndex
End Sub